# Add a min date column based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add a column to a table which shows the date for each sales ID when the first Amount hits. Essentially, I need a column which shows the first month of for each ID where the amount is NOT 0 or Null and I need it to extend for the all of the entries for that Sales ID. 
I have tried a bunch of different stuff but I cannot figure out how to get it to take all those criteria into account.

Example Data Set

```
    Sales ID            Date       Amount
0061600000g0jXOAAY  1-Nov-15    0
0061600000g0jXOAAY  1-Dec-15    0
0061600000g0jXOAAY  1-Jan-16    1479.01
0061600000g0jXOAAY  1-Feb-16    1479.01
0061600000hSBQVAA4  1-Feb-15    0
0061600000hSBQVAA4  1-Mar-15    0
0061600000hSBQVAA4  1-Apr-15    1098.18
0061600000hSBQVAA4  1-May-15    2890
```

Desired Data Set

```
    Sales ID            Date    Amount      Start Month
0061600000g0jXOAAY  1-Nov-15    0           1-Jan-16
0061600000g0jXOAAY  1-Dec-15    0           1-Jan-16
0061600000g0jXOAAY  1-Jan-16    1479.01     1-Jan-16
0061600000g0jXOAAY  1-Feb-16    1479.01     1-Jan-16
0061600000hSBQVAA4  1-Feb-15    0           1-Apr-15
0061600000hSBQVAA4  1-Mar-15    0           1-Apr-15
0061600000hSBQVAA4  1-Apr-15    1098.18     1-Apr-15
0061600000hSBQVAA4  1-May-15    2890        1-Apr-15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily calculate the start month using an aggregation query:

```
select sales_id, min(date)
from t
where amount > 0
group by sales_id;
```

Note that `> 0` also eliminates `NULL` values.

You can incorporate this into your desired result set with a `join` or correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, mindate
from t join
     (select sales_id, min(date) as mindate
      from t
      where amount > 0
      group by sales_id
     ) tt
     on t.sales_id = tt.sales_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated sub-query to get the first date for each sales_id where the amount is > 0.

```
select sales_id,date,amount,
(select min(date) from t where sales_id=t1.sales_id and amount > 0) start_month
from t t1
```

Another option would be a derived table with min date for each id.

```
select t1.sales_id,t1.date,t1.amount,m.min_date
from t t1
join (select sales_id,min(date) min_date from t where amount > 0 group by sales_id) m
on m.sales_id=t1.sales_id
```